# 'adb devices' parallel executing both on host and docker containers

Tags: android, ubuntu, docker, adb, ubuntu-16.04

I have host (Ubuntu 16.04) with two connected Android devices and docker containers for them. Every container can see his device:

```
admin@ubuntu:~$ adb devices
List of devices attached
851e4ce3        device
```

Now I need to see devices both on host and inside of containers. So I run `adb start-server` on host, and it can see both devices. But from that moment containers cannot see their phones (`adb devices` returns empty list).
And if I run `adb kill-server` on host, they would see their devices again.

Is there any way too see devices via adb on host and inside the containers at the same moment? Please help me to configure it.

Comment: did you get a fix for this ?